# Do useless values matter in training?

Tags: tensorflow

im a total beginner in working with tensorflow.

Im trying to set up a model to predict the treatment duration for patients in a dental cabinet. For training my tensorflow model i feed recorded patient data like gender, age, number of present teeth, number of caries etc., together with the actual time spent in a treatment as the target value.

Now i did some manual analysis on my patient data and figured that not all patient attributes are really relevant for predicting the outcome. For example it doesn't really matter if a patient is male or female, in average male and female patients require the same treatment time.

So does it make sense to only feed my model with relevant data which really make an impact on the outcome? Or does the nature of neural network figure out on its own which attributes play a significant role on the outcome?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what neural networks and other models are good at. They figure out what is important and what is not.

Make sure you have enough data for the neural network to learn from. Otherwise, you can choose other models such as Decision Forest.